# Chromedriver setup in Selenium (Python - Spyder)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently working on a script to web-scrape, but whenever I try to run webdriver.Chrome() I get this error: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

I've already tried downloading the chromedriver from the official page, and then pasting it to the folder in which the script with which I'm working is (C:\Users\Martin.spyder-py3), but a new error pops up.

In this case, a new Chrome window opens telling me that the connection is not private, and that an
automated testing software is controlling Chrome.

To install Selenium all I did was open the Anaconda prompt and type conda install Selenium.

My Chrome version is 80.0.3987.149

I'm working with Spyder, which I got through Anaconda.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider')
slider = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#example-1 div.slider-handle.min-slider- 
handle.round")

move = ActionChains(driver)
move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(40, 0).release().perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below solution :

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider')
slider=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#example-1 div.slider-handle.min-slider-handle.round")))


move = ActionChains(driver)
move.click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(40, 0).release().perform()
```

Comment: Hi Dipak! Thanks a lot, it now works!

If it isn't too much to aks, can you tell me what was wrong with my code (or telling me what should I look for to find it)?